# Angular.js watching the result of a function call

Tags: angularjs

Is there any ostensible issue with the following snippet:

```
  <ul id="entry-name" class="breadcrumb">
      <li ng-repeat="dir in pathElements()" class="active">
          <span ng-show="!$last">
              &nbsp;<a href="#!?path={{dir.url}}">{{ dir.name }}</a>&nbsp;<span ng-show="!$first" class="dividier">/</span> 
          </span>
      </li>
      <li class="active">{{ pathElements()[pathElements().length - 1].name }}</li>
  </ul>
```

with this js:

```
  $scope.pathElements = function() {
      var retval = [];
      var arr = $scope.currentPath().split('/');
      if (arr[0] == '') {
          arr[0] = '/';
      }

      var url = "/";
      retval.push({name: arr[0], url: url});
      for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
          if (arr[i] != '') {
              url += arr[i] + '/';
              retval.push({name: arr[i], url: url});
          }
      }
      return retval;
  };
```

This seems to be causing a "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error, but I'm not sure why. Is it because pathElements() is returning a new array each time? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Don't you think it makes sense to cache the path array? You are calling the function 3 times. Apart from that have you thought about using $routeParams?

Comment: @Flek The "path" I'm splitting up isn't the actual url path, it's a parameter being passed to the url (like `localhost:8000/#?path=/some/path`) But yeah, you're right, should probably be caching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this happens because you're returning a new array every time, and the $digest cycle loops infinitely (but Angular ceases it). You should declare it outside the function.

```js
$scope.pathArray = [];
$scope.pathElements = function() {
  // retval becomes $scope.pathArray
  if (weNeedToRecalcAllPathVariables) {
    $scope.pathArray.length = 0;
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

We use `$scope.pathArray.length = 0` instead of creating a new one, to avoid it firing continuously.

You should also consider what @Flek suggests. Call this function only once, in the time you need it to recalculate. And all you binds should be directly over `$scope.pathArray`.

If you do need a function to test its clenaning state before using it, then at least I suggest you to create two separate functions, just to keep each function with it own attribution.

Comment: Ok, this makes a lot more sense, but now I'm just not sure how to know when to update `pathArray`. The 'path' I'm getting comes from a url parameter (specifically `$location.search().path`). Can I `$watch` that expression safely?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you will need to watch a function that returns the referred value: `$scope.$watch(function() { return $location.search().path; }, function pathChanged(newValue) {});` as there is no way to bind to the services directly.

Answer (score 3):

For some nice reference on how to implement breadcrumbs in Angular check out the [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) project ([breadcrumbs service](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/breadcrumbs.js), [how to use it](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/header.tpl.html#L25)).

Here's a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnG7indQHOCAP6UsK6Bu).