# AngularJS: $watch-ing a function causes infinte $digest loop

Tags: angularjs, watch

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HhkypG8I3t7BNv7EPl8q?p=preview

I have a number of Filter objects that live in a FilterArray. The template binds to the state inside of filters. The FilterArray's job is to ascertain the total state of all the Filters using the state() function.

```
angular.module('app', [])

// A filter
.factory('Filter', function() {
  return function(state) {
    return {
      state: state
    };
  };
})

// An array of filters with a state() function
.factory('FilterArray', function(Filter) {
    return function(filters) {
      return {
        filters: filters,
        state: function() {
          return this.filters.map(function(filter) {
            return filter.state;
        });
      }
    };
  }
})

.controller('FilterCtrl', function($scope, Filter, FilterArray) {
  $scope.filterArray = new FilterArray([
    new Filter(true),
    new Filter(false)
  ]);

  $scope.$watch('filterArray.state()', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})

;
```

Now, when I try to $watch() this function, an infinite $digest loop occurs (see Plunker). The idea is that I would like to broadcast an event when the state of the FilterArray changes.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening and the correct way to architect it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490661/angular-js-watching-the-result-of-a-function-call - the problem is you are returning a new array (so a new reference) every time you call the function. Internally AngularJS's does a strict comparison between the old and new values. Arrays with different references, even if they contain the same thing, will trigger a `$digest` loop. Couple this with the fact that you have a different reference every time you call the function and you get to an infinite loop.

Comment: Makes sense. But how do I prevent the generation of a new array? The FilterArray doesn't know (and shouldn't care) what the state of its Filters is.

Comment: "Array.prototype.map()
Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) - so first of all  you cannot use `map`. You need a way of doing the map but return the same array...so a basic `for` loop instead?

Comment: Or you can add true as additional argument of $watch(), which will then do a deep equality comparison rather than a reference comparison.

Comment: Right...I'm so against deep watching that I forget that's a solution :)

Comment: I'm not sure you can get around deep watching in this case (unless we want to use events or some other mechanism). If the array is new each time, it is an infinite loop; if the array is reused, then it doesn't trigger the $watch. In other words, it seems like the trigger is dependent on the deep equality itself.